# Keeping MySQL values in sequence after deletion

Tags: mysql, triggers, sequence

Suppose I have the following table called "Test" in a MySQL database (where id is the primary key):

```
id | entry |
---+-------+
 1 |  a    | 
 2 |  b    | 
 3 |  c    | 
 4 |  c    | 
 5 |  d    | 
 6 |  e    |
```

What I would like to know is how can I keep the id values in the sequence {1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n} after deleting a row from the table. For example, say I execute the following:

```
 DELETE FROM Test WHERE id = 4;
```

Then I would like the table to look like this after deletion:

```
 id | entry |
 ---+-------+
  1 |  a    | 
  2 |  b    | 
  3 |  c    | 
  4 |  d    | 
  5 |  e    |
```

I think the solution is to use a database trigger but I'm not too sure how to create a trigger which implements this behaviour.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Well, I was planning to create a database for an online image gallery where each image would be identified by the unique id value from the table. This is so I can create a clean URL such as http://mywebsite/art/image_index where image_index is the id of the table. If some images were to be deleted from the gallery then I think it would be untidy to have image x.jpg represented by an id of 1 and it's successor, image y.jpg, represented by an id of 5 (for example) as this would be out of sequence (and not intuitive?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run this query:

```
SET @id = 0;
UPDATE `Test` SET `id` = @id:= @id + 1;
```

Although I don't know why you'd want to...